# Gradle 'apply from' import causing 'No such property' issue

Tags: gradle

I am in the process of converting a system from building with Ant to building with Gradle.  The system has multiple top-level projects that all share a common build system that is customized per-project.

I have been prototyping the new build system by writing the logic directly into the build.gradle file.  As I get closer to the final system, I need to pull the bulk of the logic out into a template build that all of the projects can extend as needed.  I have also broken the template build up into functionality-specific modules.

### Directory Structure

```
buildsupport/
  - gradle/
      - master-template.gradle
      - legacy-properties.gradle
  - build.gradle
main_module/
  - build.gradle
  - settings.gradle
module1/
  - build.gradle
module2/
  - build.gradle
```

Where the `buildsupport` component is shared between projects and contains the template build plus our JUnit category definitions.  `main_module` is the primary module that contains the top-level Gradle build file and `module1` and `module2` are submodules of the project.

#### master-template.gradle

```
apply from: 'legacy-properties.gradle'

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    ...
}
```

#### legacy-properties.gradle

```
configure(allprojects.findAll {it.name != 'buildsupport'}) {
    ...
}
```

#### main_module/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    apply from: '../buildsupport/gradle/master-template.gradle', to: this.buildscript
}
```

### Problem

When I try to run gradle from the `main_module` directory, I get the following error from Gradle:

```
* Where:
Script '[redacted]\buildsupport\gradle\legacy-properties.gradle' line: 6

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> No such property: allprojects for class: org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler
```

(Line 6 is the "`buildscript {`" line of `legacy-properties.gradle`.)

How can I get Gradle to properly import the `legacy-properties.gradle` through the `master-template.gradle` script into the `main_module` project?

Answer (score 0):

After a little messing around, I found out that the order that I import configurations matters.  I was applying the `legacy-properties.gradle` file before the `allprojects` block in `master-template.gradle`, which is what applies the `java` plugin, which declares the `sourceSets` block.  By moving the "`apply from`" to be after the `allprojects` block, the script now compiles.